# Setting up an Automated Texting Service

Tags: service

Attempting to set up an automated texting service for customers, where people can text a number, and get an automated response from some sort of server. The cellphone user should be able to hold some sort of exchange with the server through text. Any one have any idea how to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set up a server to respond to MO (Mobile Originated) messages.

You need to have a relationship with an SMS provider/aggregator that will forward MO messages to your server. Based on keywords, you can decide how to respond - since you have the originating phone number you can easily reply to the sender.

I have developed systems like this, so if you need more details just ask.